# Embed videos which have no control options and close option in HTML document

Tags: html, html5-video

**I am trying to embed a video file (mp4) into my HTML document. I would like this video to play without being paused and without being closed/minimized.**

`<video width="320" height="240">
    <source src="mov.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>`

I am using this code to play a video in HTML. But I am not able to remove controls from the video. If I right click on the video, I still get the control options.

So I would like to know if there is a way to disable controls on this video or use another player which can remove controls.

**I would also like to know if I can dynamically write some display data on the video space while it is being played.**

Comment: This W3 page may help you. http://j.mp/17pTZgS

Comment: yeah I checked the W3 site but it does not talk about removing the controls completely, you can only remove it from the display but if you right click on the video you will be able to see the controls are still available.

Comment: If you only need a "loosey" restrict, you can either listen to `oncontextmenu` event and `preventDefault()`, or use a transparent `div` to "cover" the `video` element.

Comment: oh ok. That sounds much simpler :) Thanks